# How To Prevent Duplicate Entry into “Date/Time” field in MS Access 2013 Table

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a table called “Test_Daily”.  Actually I want to stop / prevent to enter same Date into its “Today_Date” field. Below is my Code, working fine for other fields, but when I try it on Date/Time field, gives me an Error that “Data Type miss Match”. Below is my code, anyone can help.

Code :

```vb
Private Sub btnTempCheckDup_Click()

    Dim Vr_newDate As String
    Dim VR_linkCriteria As String

    Vr_newDate = Me.txtTempSave.Value
    VR_linkCriteria = "[Today_Date] = " & "'" & Vr_newDate & "'"

    If Me.txtTempSave = DLookup("[Today_Date]", "Test_Table", VR_linkCriteria) Then
        MsgBox "This Date " & Vr_newDate & " Has Already Entered into the Database"
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a correctly formatted string expression for the date:

```
Vr_newDate = Format(Me.txtTempSave.Value, "yyyy\/mm\/dd")
VR_linkCriteria = "[Today_Date] = #" & Vr_newDate & "#"
```

Answer (score 1):

if you just want to prevent duplicate entries in the field, you can set the Properties of the field in Access to have the date field be indexed. it's not a VBA solution, but it works.